# In which file does the syscall num defined in linux 3.13?

Tags: linux, assembly, system-calls

I want to know that where does the syscall num defined?And the type is like
*#define __NR_exit  1*
*#define __NR_read  3*
Thanks a lot for your answers .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to find the syscall number defines in [unistd.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?v=3.13&i=__NR_read) for the appropriate architecture, and the corresponding `sys_`-functions with argument information in [syscalls.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?v=3.13;i=sys_read).